# Mockito con Eclipse error: "this.controlador" is null

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, mockito

estoy probando para realizar pruebas unitarias con Mockito en un proyecto test que he creado para ese propósito. La clase test es esta:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SuperHeroeControllerTest {

    @Mock
    public SuperHeroeService superHeroeService = mock(SuperHeroeService.class);
    
    @InjectMocks
    private SuperHeroeController controlador;
    
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        
        
        SuperHeroeModel sh1 = new SuperHeroeModel(Long.valueOf(10) , "Pedro", "volar", 1);
        
        //Cuando llames a este método más adelante devuelve el objeto creado???
        when(superHeroeService.obtenerPorId(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(sh1));
    }
    
    /*
    @Test
    void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }*/
    
    @Test
    public void testObtenerSuper() {
        
        Optional<SuperHeroeModel> valor = controlador.obtenerUsuarioPorId(Long.valueOf(10));
        
        assertEquals("Pedro", valor.get().getNombre());
    }

}
```

Pero por algún motivo al hacer el test con Maven a través de Eclipse, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.superheroes.superheroes.controllers.SuperHeroeController.obtenerUsuarioPorId(java.lang.Long)" because "this.controlador" is null
    at com.superheroes.superheroes.controllers.SuperHeroeControllerTest.testObtenerSuper(SuperHeroeControllerTest.java:53)
```

¿Por qué me sale entonces ese error?

Gracias! Ignacio

Comment: Por las dudas: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](/q/42977)

Comment: Hola Ignacio. ¿Qué versión de junit estás usando? Considera aclararlo en tu pregunta. Échale un vistazo también a las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41584454/8838721).

Comment: Hoy en dia la programación se ha vuelto demasiado dependiente de los frameworks 

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher una vez más tu comentario no aporta nada a la publicación y no viene al caso. Parece que te dedicas a ir publicación por publicación haciendo comentarios sobre dependencias que no aportan nada y ni siquiera tienen base alguna. ¿Programas en java? ¿Qué se supone debería usar para sus pruebas unitarias según tú?

Comment: La versión de JUnit es la última, en las dependencias de Maven no especifico versión por lo que coge la última. Por otro lado, la llamada a controlador.obtenerUsuarioPorId(Long.valueOf(10)) NO es null ya que se dispara el when establecido en el setUp devolviendo el superHeroe creado....

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear el objeto controlador, lo declaras pero no lo instancias.

```
SuperHeroeController controlador = new SuperHeroeController()
```

Y así lo puedes utilizar.